# Local stability estimate for divergence free vector field

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, divergence-operator, singular-integrals

For a divergence free field $w\in [L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)]^d$, especially for $d = 3$, it is well known that there exists a skew-symmetric matrix $\psi \in [W^{1,2}_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^d)]^{d\times d}$ with $\nabla \psi_{ij} \in [L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)]^d$ such that
$w = \text{div }\psi$, the divergence of the matrix $\psi$ is computed along its rows and the following estimates exists:
$$
\|\nabla \psi_{ij}\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)} \leq C \|w\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)}.
$$

On any bounded region $\omega$ and $\Omega$ with Lipschitz boundary or any nice properties and $\omega \subset \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$, I wonder whether we still have the same type estimate for the above $\psi_{ij}$ and $w$:
$$
\|\nabla \psi_{ij}\|_{L^2(\omega)} \leq C' \|w\|_{L^2(\omega)},
$$
where $C'$ is independent of $\omega$ but could depend on $\Omega$.